# APINotAllowedError while getting recent photos from instagram

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I am getting the following error while using the media/recent API.

```
{
  "meta": {
    "error_type": "APINotAllowedError",
    "code": 400,
    "error_message": "This tag cannot be viewed"
  }
}
```

I have tried with client Id and access token.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/mytag/media/recent?client_id=clientId
```

or

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/mytag?access_token=accesstokem
```

Also, I created new App in different Instagram account and tried. It gives me the same error.

Only for particular hashtag I am getting this error, for other hashtags I am getting the proper response.

Please help me.